# jQuery .val() returns empty when control has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a function

```
var saveName = function (aName) {
        console.log(aName);
        $("#hiddenFieldName").val(aName);
    }
```

which is called on button click and certain value from the button is stored into the hidden field. Then, after postback, I want to print the value into console

```
$(function () {
            console.log("The value is " + $("#hiddenFieldName").val());
            });
```

but I am getting only "The value is ". It seems, as if there was nothing stored in the hidden field. Even when displaying the code in console (F12, tried both in Chrome and IE), the value there is empty. However, when displaying source code, I can see the value stored in the hidden field. Does anybody know, what might be the problem?

Comment: Could you please reproduce this issue in a live example? The problem isn't clear from the information you've provided.

Comment: We need some additional information: What type of field is using the Id '#hiddenFieldName'? Is it an inputbox or text field?

Comment: your code is fine, the problem lies somewhere else! http://jsfiddle.net/rbtuhp4k/

Comment: It's an ASP Hidden field <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenFieldName" ClientIDMode="Static" />, equivalent to <input type="hidden" />... and the ID is correct, if you would ask.

Comment: are you resetting the hidden field value at server side ?? Please give us code snippet of postback event ..

Comment: The code behind is empty, so far, so I guess the problem will not be on the server side.

Comment: @AminJafari what do you mean by "somewhere else"? I tried to change the fiddle, so it would resemble my code, but I am getting ReferenceError http://jsfiddle.net/1dhp5659/9/

Comment: @Storm: Here's an updated fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/1dhp5659/15/

Comment: It may be because of the content you are trying to get a value for is added/inserted after the DOM was initially loaded. Try looking into "Event Delegation"( learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation ) Hopefully this will help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> Even when displaying the code in **console** (F12, tried both in Chrome
>   and IE), the value there is empty. However, when displaying **source**
>   **code**, I can see the value stored in the hidden field.

I get the sense that there must be some other js on the page that is writing `""` into the value for that hidden field. That way, when you view the source, the value from the server is correct because no js has run yet, but when you look in console or inspector, because the client page has executed the js in question, it has cleared the value.

Comment: Your sense is almost right, I do write "", but to a different control. The functions above are the only ones that get/set value to the hidden field.

Comment: Just for my sanity, can you put your logging code outside of the document.ready, but after the hidden input tag? Reason being that if your source code shows the right value, then it must be there on the page when it loads. There should be no difference between viewing source and the initial state of the DOM until js touches it.

Comment: I tried it and got the same result. However, the problem might be the ASP controls, which have their own lifecycle... otherwise, it's still a mystery to me.

Comment: asp controls have no lifecycle stage that says "only if the browser is asking for the source of the page, maintain state, otherwise, do whatever". In fact, I don't think the browser even exposes anything to the server that stipulates whether or not the request is for a source-view or an actual page load AFAIK. One thing to check is if you have `ViewState` disabled for the hidden control or the page in general, which is what does the magical postback-save-state mullarkey.

Comment: It may be because of the content you are trying to get a value for is added/inserted after the DOM was initially loaded. Try looking into "Event Delegation"( http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/  ) Hopefully this will help solve your problem.

Comment: @Mark we all seem to be having lots of feelings about this question ;)